# can you explain what this javascript code does?

Tags: arrays, for-loop, alert, nested-loops

```
var fName = ["Sean", "Niel", "Patt", "Jimmy", "John", "Sam"];
var lName = ["Paker", "Hamilton", "Shaker"];
var fullName = [];
var f = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < fName.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < lName.length; j++) {
    fullName[f] = fName[i] +" " + lName[j];
    f++;
  }
}
alert(fullName[0]);
```

Can you explain what is going on on this code?

Comment: Just execute/debug the code and take a look at the fullName array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This code creates a list of combinations of the first names given in **fName** with the last names given in **lName**. The two loops, loop through the list elements and concatenate the two strings to form 6*3 combinations. To be precise:

```
fullName[0] = "Sean Paker"
fullName[1] = "Sean Hamilton"
fullName[2] = "Sean Shaker"
fullName[3] = "Niel Paker"
fullName[4] = "Niel Hamilton"
....
```

and so on

Finally there is an alert(pop up) to show fullName[0] which is "Sean Paker"

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me like that code is putting every combination of first name and last name in the `fullName` array then alerting only the first one.